# SQL Create View and using it in Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have the following function and I need to take out the `SELECT` part and create a separate view.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.dbf_get_penalty_points
(      @pn_seq_party_id          NUMERIC(18),
       @pv_penalty_points_code   CHAR(1) = 'Y') -- Use 'N' for total points, otherwise will return Current Penalty Points

RETURNS NUMERIC(18,0)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @n_penalty_points       NUMERIC(18),
           @d_latest_points_date   DATETIME

   SELECT @d_latest_points_date = dbo.dbf_trunc_date(DateAdd(mm, - Abs(Convert(NUMERIC(18,0),dbo.dbf_get_sys_param('CMS2', 'PP_MONTHS'))), GetDate()))

   SELECT @n_penalty_points = IsNull(Sum(penalty_points_amount),0)
     FROM dbo.ar_penalty_point WITH(NOLOCK) 
    WHERE seq_party_id = @pn_seq_party_id
      AND 1 = CASE
                 WHEN @pv_penalty_points_code = 'N' THEN 1
                 WHEN @pv_penalty_points_code = 'Y' AND added_date >= @d_latest_points_date AND reset_date IS NULL THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
              END

   RETURN @n_penalty_points
END

GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.dbf_get_penalty_points TO standard
GO
```

I have tried and got this,

```
 SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN added_date >=dbo.dbf_trunc_date(DateAdd(mm, - Abs(Convert(NUMERIC(18,0),dbo.dbf_get_sys_param('CMS2', 'PP_MONTHS'))), GetDate()))
                    AND reset_date IS NULL THEN 1 
                    ELSE 0) current_points,
           IsNull(Sum(penalty_points_amount),0) total_points,
           seq_party_id
     FROM dbo.ar_penalty_point WITH(NOLOCK) 
          GROUP BY seq_party_id
```

Now I need to get rid of

```
dbo.dbf_trunc_date(DateAdd(mm, - Abs(Convert(NUMERIC(18,0),dbo.dbf_get_sys_param('CMS2', 'PP_MONTHS'))), GetDate()))
```

From the `SELECT` part of the query. I am struck is there a better way to write my view ?

**EDIT**
The objective is to create a view that returns total_points and current_points. For better understanding refer the `CREATE` part following

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.dbf_get_penalty_points
(      @pn_seq_party_id          NUMERIC(18),
       @pv_penalty_points_code   CHAR(1) = 'Y') -- Use 'N' for total points, otherwise will return Current Penalty Points
```

Refer to **-- Use 'N' for total points, otherwise will return Current Penalty Points** in the comments

Comment: Why do you need to extract part of it into a view? What's the overall objective?

Comment: To tidy up the proc and use views. The objective is to move the `SELECT` part to a view.

Comment: Just realised why your question looked so drab - when posting code, highlight the block and hit the `{}` button (or just indent every line by four spaces) rather than using a `<pre>` tag - that way, it turns the syntax highlighter on.

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever I will have that on mind for my next posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN (t.added_date >= t.target_date
                AND t.reset_date IS NULL) THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 END) current_points,
       IsNull(Sum(t.penalty_points_amount),0) total_points,
       t.seq_party_id
 FROM (
   SELECT dbo.dbf_trunc_date(DateAdd(mm, - Abs(Convert(NUMERIC(18,0),dbo.dbf_get_sys_param('CMS2', 'PP_MONTHS'))), GetDate())) as target_date,
        u.reset_date, u.penalty_points_amount,u.seq_party_id,u.added_date  FROM
dbo.ar_penalty_point as u ) as t GROUP BY  t.seq_party_id
```